# How can I convert a list of dictionaries into a dictionary of lists in ansible?

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

It's kind of a challenge for me to use correct ansible filters.
Can someone help me with how I can convert a list of dictionaries?

This is my input data:

```yaml
"_list_of_dict":
[
        {
            "groupid": "11",
            "hostname": "host1.local",
            "timeout": "5000",
            "status": "ONLINE",
        },
        {
            "groupid": "12",
            "hostname": "host1.local",
            "timeout": "5000",
            "status": "ONLINE",
        },
        {
            "groupid": "12",
            "hostname": "host2.local",
            "timeout": "5000",
            "status": "ONLINE",
        }
    ]
```

And this what I would like to get:

```yaml
"_dict_of_list": {
        "12": [
            {
                "hostname": "host2.local",
                "timeout": "5000",
                "status": "ONLINE",
            },
            {
                "host": "host1.local",
                "timeout": "5000",
                "status": "ONLINE",
            }
        ],
        "11": [
            {
                "host": "host1.local",
                "timeout": "5000",
                "status": "ONLINE",
            }
        ],
```

It might be that the list contains different numbers of `groupid` and each group could have different numbers of hosts and I have to combine them by `groupid`.

Comment: `It's kind of a challenge for me to use correct ansible filters` <=  For your information since you are new here, it is usually expected from posters that they give some evidence of what they have already tried and what is the exact problem they are stuck at. See [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [creating a minimal examle](/help/mcve) as well as [How much effort is awaited from SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Concerning your question, please have a look at the [jinja2 `groupby` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.groupby)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself.
That works for me.
Thanks, to everyone who tried to help I really appreciate it.

```
    _dict_of_list: >-
          {{ _dict_of_list | default({})
            | combine({item.groupid: []
            + [{
                'hostname': item.hostname,
                'timeout': item. timeout,
                'status': item. status
              }]
            + _dict_of_list[item.groupid] | default([]) })
          }}
  with_items: "{{ _list_of_dict }}"
```

Comment: My problem was different, but your solution helped me find my own way.  Thanks and welcome to SO.